# How to solve Unicode character issue in mysql with rails functionality

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got an error `Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\xAE\xE0\xA5\x81...` in log while running a query.

I identified the reason for the error is MySql database not fully support the Unicode character. some blog suggest to migrate the database to utf8mb4.

But i want a solution with minimum change by using rails or ruby functionality. How we can use escape the unicode character before trying write in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not have an option to escape the data.

but we can set encode type utf8bin for a specific column in db instead of migrate whole db.

Add a migration to change the column

```
reversible do |dir|
      dir.up {
        change_column :transaction_details, :merchant, "VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin"
      }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two things in order for this to work:

- All character columns must be set to type `utf8mb4`
- The database connection must be `encoding: utf8mb4` in your `config/database.yml`

Once both of those are set the data should flow through correctly. There's no alternative but to set the encoding correctly. You can't "escape" these as they're valid data, or would be if the column type is `utf8mb4`. The MySQL database engine is rejecting them as being invalid for that encoding.

MySQL supports 4-byte UTF-8 if and only if you set encoding as `utf8mb4`. This is unusual as other databases like Postgres do this out of the box without differentiating between 1-3 byte UTF-8 and 4-byte UTF-8.

Comment: The error happen when i move the data from one  table column to another table column. if it not supported at all how get saved in existing table

Comment: It depends on the encoding you're using and how you're moving it. Make sure everything is `utf8m4b`.